# Find the current element being replaced with jquery .replaceWith()

Tags: jquery

Basically a bunch of elements that I don't really want are rendered, so I want to take the text of these elements and render it into different elements. So I thought, yay, `.replaceWith()` in jQuery will make this a doddle.

```
$('.register .hint').replaceWith('<div class="tooltip">' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
```

However, `$(this)` of course refers to the document, not the element I am acting my replace on. It is easily solved with...

```
$('.register .hint').each(function () {
     $(this).replaceWith('<div class="tooltip help"> <span>?</span><div class="content"><b></b><p>' + $(this).text() + '</p></div></div>');
});
```

I was just wondering if there was a way to get the element I am acting on within the first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/#replaceWith-function) takes a callback function

```
$('.register .hint').replaceWith(function () {
    return '<div class="tooltip">' + $(this).text() + '</div>';
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eanYR/)

Comment: Ah, of course, I somehow missed that in the documentation. Thanks very much